# Why aren't my internal links working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, without this code in my `.htaccess` file, none of my internal links on my site work.

But with it in my `.htaccess` file, I am recieving a ton of `HTTP/1.1 500` errors and a few `302` errors.

This is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I tried changing `%{REQUEST_URI}` to `%{HTTP_HOST}`. That fixed the internal link problem, but the errors are still there.

How would I modify this to remove all the errors I am receiving, and so that my internal links work?

PS. My site in built in Joomla.

---

If needed, this is my full `.htaccess` file":

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
</IfModule>
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candoboatloans\.com\.au
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.candoboatloans\.com\.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candoboatloans\.com\.au/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.html [L]

#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]



# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

    # Check if this looks like a mobile device
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

    # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
    # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
    # Now redirect to the mobile site
    RewriteRule ^ http://m.candoboatloans.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: That is your entire `.htaccess` file? Post the complete file.

Comment: Hey @Prix. Nah it isn't. Would you like me to post it?

Comment: Otherwise we can't tell exactly what the issue is, if possible also state how is your folders structure for example: `/home/youraccount/public_html/` equals domain.com and also where the joomla is installed?

Comment: @Prix - Added my full `.htaccess` file. My site is located inside `public_html` and my Joomla install is within the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, its based of joomla's default `.htaccess` with the needed parts from your `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
    </IfModule>
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use
RewriteEngine On

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)
RewriteBase /

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.candoboatloans.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirect to www if not www.domain or m.domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candoboatloans\.com\.au
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.candoboatloans\.com\.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

# If it ends with index.php and is not m.domain redirect to www.domain.com/content
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candoboatloans\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect all variations of index and default to www.domain.com/
# exception of index.php which should not be redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(default|index)\.(s?html?|pl|aspx?|cfm)[\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works quite well :) Unfortunately, I am still receiving a few errors, and it seems like it is just from `RewriteRule (.*) index.php`. I remove it, and the errors are gone, along with the internal links not working. When I place it back in, the internal links work, although I receive some errors. Is this fixable at all?

Comment: @fizzix What errors are you getting exactly? **If you can list the errors as detailed as possible as in what you try and what they should do but aren't doing I might be able to help you.**

Comment: If you travel to this page: http://www.ragepank.com/redirect-check/ and type in my domain name being `candoboatloans.com.au`, you will see three red errors. These are the ones that I am trying to fix.

Comment: @fizzix I see, but for example index.htm does not exist and index.html leads to 404 would you like that to go to your index page `domain.com/`?

Comment: What do you recommend? Will any of these errors hurt at all? The client has asked me to remove all these errors unfortunately.

Comment: Try the update above it should end all those 404 and red errors I believe.

Comment: @fizzix never mind my last comment it seems with this new update it is all fixed up now.

Comment: Sorry, a little confused. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @fizzix I was probably trying to visit the site when you changed the `.htaccess` so I saw a 404 but then I tried it again and it was working just fine that's all ;P

Comment: Prix - I am now unable to log into my Joomla dashboard... Whenever I try to login, it basically just 'reloads' the login page. Any ideas? The login page is `mydomain.com/administrator`

Comment: @fizzix you mean you can't access that specific page or that after you input your login credentials it redirects you?

Comment: When I enter my details and press 'login', it just reloads the page instead of logging me in and showing me my dashboard.

Comment: @fizzix mmm hard to tell try removing the last rule but I don't think that's the problem. Would have to look into it but it may not be because of the rules.

Comment: I found that it was because of this rule: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candoboatloans\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] `

Comment: Either I remove it and just cop the error, or I find an alternative solution.

Comment: @fizzix Well basically that rule tells that if the URL is anything/index.php to redirect to the index so if your admin page is something like `/administrator/index.php` it would redirect and not let you in. That rule was from your previous `.htaccess`. So yes it would be better if you remove that.